# keep right position label x-axis jquery flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, flot

I'm finding about `jquery flot`.

So, i had a problem, that i want to hard fix grid value on `x-axis`.

For examples:

It will update realtime.

`[4:02, 5:02, 6:02, 7:02, 8:02, 9:02]` after 1 hour, it only change label value and keep right position.

4:02 become 5:02 and keep right position, 5:02 become 6:02 and keep right position,...

[image]

Hope every body can support me, thank you very much.

Here is my demo: [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/khanhpn/g2CTz/484/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of only adding new ticks after each hour you have to generate the complete tick array after every update with something like this (updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/485/)):

```
var first_hour = data_speed_hour[0][0];
options_hour.xaxis.ticks = [
    first_hour,
    first_hour + 3600000*1,
    first_hour + 3600000*2,
    first_hour + 3600000*3,
    first_hour + 3600000*4,
    first_hour + 3600000*5,
    first_hour + 3600000*6 //- 600000
  ];
```